# Core Data memory allocation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

In my app I am using core data to store information. When the app is initially launched this block of code is called to fetch the data:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Customer" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
request.entity = entity;

NSError *error = nil;

Array = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest: request error: &error] mutableCopy];
NSArray * reversedArray = [[Array reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
[Array release];
Array = nil;
[request release];
[error release];
```

So everything works correctly but there is a very large amount of memory allocated that isn't getting released and I can't seem to figure it out. You can see by the screenshots below. Any help would be great.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

I originally accepted the answer below but it doesn't seem to get rid of the issue 100 percent. CFData (store) is still allocating a lot of memory which isn't getting freed. This eventually is causing a crash on an iPad 2 which I didn't experience when I accepted the answer below because I was only testing on an iPad 4. I hope this clears everything up.

**EDIT 2**

So I've been doing more testing and debugging and it seems that the more entries that are added to core data the larger the CFData (store) is getting. Currently there are only 10 separate entries in the database and the allocation from fetching them is more then 25mb when the app is opened. The main entity "Customer" has multiple relationships with other bigger entities. So when I preform the fetch of "Customer", every entity that it has a relationship with is being fetched which is causing the huge memory allocation. Is there a way to get around this issue?

I'm guessing there has to be a better way to set up how the entries are added and how they are fetched.

Here is the code for how an entry is created:

```
- (void) addItem
{
// Insert a new record in the database
Customer * customerItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Customer" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

System * system = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"System" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

Form1 * form1 =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Form1" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

Form2 * form2 =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Form2" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

Form3 * form3 =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Form3" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

Form4 * form4 =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Form4" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

Form6 * form6 =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Form6" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

Form7 * form7 =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Form7" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

Form8 * form8 =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Form8" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

Form9 * form9 =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Form9" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

Form10 * form10 =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Form10" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

Form11 * form11 =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Form11" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

customerItem.system = system;
customerItem.form1 = form1;
customerItem.form2 = form2;
customerItem.form3 = form3;
customerItem.form4 = form4;
customerItem.form6 = form6;
customerItem.form7 = form7;
customerItem.form8 = form8;
customerItem.form9 = form9;
customerItem.form10 = form10;
customerItem.form11 = form11;

// Insert a new item in the table's data source
[customerArray insertObject: customerItem atIndex: 0];

[managedObjectContext save: &error];

// Insert a new row in the table
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 0 inSection: 0];
[table insertRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: What happens to `reversedArray` after the code above finishes? It's holding on to all the fetched objects, but you don't give any indication of what happens to it. As long as it continues to exist, so do the fetched objects.

Comment: I updated my code to the answer below so reversedArray is getting autoreleased

Comment: How much of a difference did @ipmcc's answer make? You said it wasn't 100%, so how much? 1%? 50%? 99%?

Comment: Refer to Edit 2. I've seemed to narrow it down to why it is happening but I'm just not sure how to solve the issue. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Have you read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMemory.html and considered whether it could be a retain cycle issue?

Comment: @Tommy I will look at this now. I found a work around but it's still not the right solution. Basically on viewWillAppear I load everything into reversedArray and on viewWillDisappear I release the array. This frees up the memory for all the other entries in core data except for the one that is selected. I still think this will eventually lead to a crash if enough entries are added to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is going to have some amount of long-lived memory that it needs to in order to perform its function. That said, you can be extra sure you've minimized memory use here by wrapping this code in an `@autorelease` pool, like this:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Customer" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
    request.entity = entity;

    NSError *error = nil;

    Array = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest: request error: &error] mutableCopy];
    NSArray * reversedArray = [[[Array reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] retain];
    [Array release];
    Array = nil;
    [request release];
    [error release];
}
[reversedArray autorelease];
```

Even though you have been careful to release all the objects that you create, the autorelease pattern is used extensively throughout the system frameworks.

Note that with the addition of this `@autoreleasepool`, you need to retain `reversedArray` in order for it to last across the exiting of the pool's scope. I added `[reversedArray autorelease]` afterward so the code is semantically identical to the code you posted (except for the releasing of any autoreleased objects created by the execution of the fetch request.)