# Render in context memory allocation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418063/core-data-memory-allocation) question earlier about memory allocation issue and was able to fix it with some help. I'm have another issue which can be seen in the screenshot below. I've tried a few different examples that I've seen online that help release the image context but nothing seems to work. Any help would be great.

BTW I missed [localPool drain] in the screenshot. It's the next line.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your issue is:

> release the image context but nothing seems to work

Call `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` and store it in a `CGContextRef` variable. Use this variable in your functions, not a new call to get a context.

Then, when you are finished drawing, call `CGContextRelease()`.

Comment: `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` doesn't delegate the object ownership to the caller.

Comment: I did not say that. But the method is opaque, so you do not know what exactly the memory implications are. That's why it makes sense to avoid calling it too often.